# Angular ng-init $scope function not updating model properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a web application just as a test now. Right now the main features are login and posting a message.

When the user presses a button, the following code is executed:

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('/messages').
        then(function(response) {
            if(angular.toJson(response.data.messages) != angular.toJson($scope.messages)) {
                $scope.messages = response.data.messages;
                $scope.clearAllSelected();
                $scope.confirmRestOperation(response);
            }
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.messages = [];
            $scope.confirmRestOperation(response);
        });
};
```

The HTML template dependent off of my model is as follows:

```
<div id="messages">
<md-card ng-repeat="message in messages" class="padding-medium box-sizing" ng-init="setAuthorDataFromAuthorId(message.author)">
  <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-click="toggle(message.id, selected)" ng-model="exists(message.id, selected)"></md-checkbox>
  <h4><b>Author: {{authorData[message.author].name}} ({{authorData[message.author].username}})</b></h4>
  <img style="width:50px;height:50px;" ng-src="{{authorData[message.author].profile_picture}}" alt="(Picture)">
  <p>Message: {{message.message}}</p>
  <p>{{message.time | timestampToDate}}</p>
</md-card>
</div>
```

So the goal here is, the message object will contain `author` field which contains the ID of the author. On each card initialization I call a `$scope` function called `setAuthorDataFromAuthorId`, this takes in an integer value, the ID of the author who wrote the post. The following code is this:

```
$scope.setAuthorDataFromAuthorId = function(id) { // line 22
    console.log($scope.authorData);               // line 23
    if(id in $scope.authorData) return;
    console.log("setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called");
    $http.get('/getUserDataFromId/'+id).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);               // line 27
        console.log($scope.authorData);           // line 28
        $scope.authorData[id] = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log($scope.authorData);
        $scope.authorData = {};
    });
    console.log("setAuthorFromAuthorId has been completed");

};
```

See my goal here is say there are 50 messages on the screen (obviously not realistic in any production scenario to load every single message in the database, but for a test site this is what it's doing), I don't want it to access the api endpoint `/getUserDataFromId/1` 50 different times if the same message is from the same author. My goal here is to see if the id is already a key in our `$scope.authorData` object. If so, we return a save ourselves a trip to the endpoint and loading and writing information. So in a perfect world, all 50 messages would load and in the console we would see only this:

```
Object {}
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been completed
Object {id: author data here}
```

This would happen because it would load the author information one time, and the remaining 49 it would see that the id is a key in the `authorData` object and it would not get past the first line in the above JS function. However here are the results:

```
Object {} MessageController.js:23
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called MessageController.js:25
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been completed MessageController.js:35

Object {} MessageController.js:23
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called MessageController.js:25
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been completed MessageController.js:35

Object {full author data here from api response} MessageController.js:27 
Object {} MessageController.js:28
Object {full author data here from api response} MessageController.js:27
Object {1: Object} (correct $scope.authorData) MessageController.js:28
```

I do not understand this output at all. It is as if the `ng-init` is only calling the couple lines of the function, and deferring the rest until later to actually work and update the model. I did some research and tried adding some `$scope.$watch()`'s and `$scope.$apply()`'s and digests after certain key lines of code to try and get the model to update properly but it keeps running the first console.log before the conditional as many times as there are messages, and then later it skips that part, and runs all the `$http.get()` as many times as there are messages, and undermines my want to save ourselves from reaching the API endpoint too many useless times.

After some thinking I decided to change the `ng-init` to `ng-click` and see if this worked at all. It was perfect. If there were 50 message all from the same user and I clicked on one, they all updated(because the model was properly updated) and if I clicked any more times after that the API would not be reached any more because the function is working how it lexically should be working. Here was the output after changing the `ng-init` to `ng-click`:

```
Object {} MessageController.js:23
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called MessageController.js:25
setAuthorFromAuthorId has been completed MessageController.js:35
Object {full author data from API} MessageController.js:27
Object {} MessageController.js:28 // this is the authorData before it was updated with the above data
Object {1: Object} MessageController.js:23
Object {1: Object} MessageController.js:23
Object {1: Object} MessageController.js:23
Object {1: Object} MessageController.js:23 // this would happen as many times as I clicked, which is the correct response
```

Any recommendations as to how I can get this to work properly and as expected (to me at least) with `ng-init` or at least some reasoning as to why it is failing with `ng-init`?

My gut tells me perhaps I cam trying to read or write something a value before it has been written, this would warrant a `$scope.$watch()` however I have tried it (perhaps not correctly though!).

Thanks

Comment: this probably isn't possible with `ng-init`.  The documentation for `ng-init` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/ is very clear that it is only appropriate in a few specific instances, and outside those special situations, it may or may not perform correctly, due to it being a directive with a priority.  Other directives with a higher priority may execute earlier, expecting the result which hasn't been processed yet.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea what I could use here as an `ng-init` alternative? I have done some research and it doesn't seem like there's a lot I can replace it with to load values

Comment: also, you are using `$http` which is async, and then trying to make another `$http` async call based on the result of the first async call.  essentially, even if the first and the second `message` have the same `author`, the second one is looking for that same `author` before the first has returned the data, causing it to make another call for the same data.

Comment: This is an ideal case to switch to `$resource`, which can automatically cache server requests.  You also can create your own cache for specific requests, using `$cacheFactory`, but this can be a bit of a challenge to implement perfectly.

Comment: It might be easy to implement in this case just because the request I'd be doing is so simple and there's really only one place in this controller I'd use the $resource, however my question is: 

What if some user data gets asynchronously change and the cached  `/getUserDataFromInfo` thus giving me the wrong value technically. That's quite a reach in this instance since nothing will be changing this fast (the time it takes to load 50 messages or so), but the principle is the same so how could I deal with that in general or is that something that can't be dealt with really, hence the caching?

Comment: yeah, you really basically can only have it one way or the other;  The purpose of using `$cacheFactory` is to force multiple calls to the same endpoint to all use the result of a single call, which in turn means that those subsequent calls won't get the opportunity to check to see if the server data is newer.  That's a tradeoff you have to plan for.

Comment: Ok, so does it make sense to just not do the conditional check, and set `$scope.authorData[id]` equal to the `$scope.resource('/apiEndpoint')` which will either be a cached copy, or new data returned from an api call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget `ng-init`, move the initialization inside the controller.

**Chain** from the first `$http` request.

When the user presses a button, execute the following code:

```
$scope.getDataAndInitPromise = function() {
  $scope.pendingFlags = $scope.pendingFlags || {};
  var promises = [];

  //compute getDataPromise
  var getDataPromise = $scope.getDataPromise();

  //chain from getDataPromise
  var initListPromise = getDataPromise.then (function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(m) { 
       var id = m.author;
       if ($scope.pendingFlags[id] == "pending") return;
       if(id in $scope.authorData) return;
       console.log("setAuthorFromAuthorId has been called");
       //set pending flag
       $scope.pendingFlags[id] = "pending";
       var p = $http.get('/getUserDataFromId/'+id
                ).then(function(response) {
                    console.log($scope.authorData);
                    $scope.authorData[id] = response.data;
               }).catch(function(error) {
                    //log error     
               }).finally ( function() {
                    console.log("setAuthorId %s done ", id);
                    //clear pending flag
                    $scope.pendingFlags[id] = "done";
               });
        //push out promises
        promises.push(p);
    });
    //return promises array for further chaining
    return promises;
  });
  //return for further chaining
  return initListPromise;
}
```

Notice the use of `pendingFlags` to prevent a repeat fetch if a fetch is already in process. Also notice that I moved the `console.log` report of "done" into a `.finally` method.

Of course modify, `getData` to return a promise for chaining.

```
$scope.getDataPromise = function(){
  var  getDataPromise = 
    $http.get('/messages').
        then(function(response) {
            if(angular.toJson(response.data.messages) != angular.toJson($scope.messages)) {
                $scope.messages = response.data.messages;
                $scope.clearAllSelected();
                $scope.confirmRestOperation(response);
            }
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.messages = [];
            $scope.confirmRestOperation(response);
        });
  //return promise for chaining 
  return getDataPromise;
};
```

**Leverage the power of promises.**

Don't throw away those httpPromises; use them.